# How to get complex parameter from url with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having the following url:

```
localhost/tag/Visi%C3%B3n%20Urbana/La%20Florida/I125#plantas
```

I need to capture the parameter `Visión Urbana` that is right after `tag` word...

As you can realize this parameter contains an `ó` that makes url transform with weird codes, and it also contain white spaces that are replaced with `%`.

What I need to do is to capture this parameter with jquery in its original presentation? Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: will it always be in the same place? also if it returns true instead of the string would that work?

Comment: no just use decodeURI

Answer (score 3):

Decode and split. e.g.

```js
const url = 'localhost/tag/Visi%C3%B3n%20Urbana/La%20Florida/I125#plantas';
const tag = decodeURIComponent(url).split('/')[2]

console.log(tag);
```

This assumes the tag to be the third element.